# Aws Codebuild java 17 runtime environment in aws/codebuild/windows-base:2019-2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-codebuild

I am trying to build a JavaFx application in AWS CodeBuild Windows 2019 Server machine. The application needs java 14 or above version as it uses jpackage for packing windows installer which is not available in java 11. But AWS CodeBuild does not have java 14 runtime.

I tried to build the application with java 17 by setting the runtime-version to corretto17.

```yaml
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto17
```

I checked the java version in the build machine with  `java --version` . It uses java 11 even after setting corretto17.

```
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.15.9.1 (build 11.0.15+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.15.9.1 (build 11.0.15+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Here, [AWS docs says corretto17 is available in windows-base:2019-2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html#windows-runtimes)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html#windows-runtimes), these are the available runtimes, depending on the server version:

[image: Windows image runtimes]

If you're using version 1.0, only Corretto 11 is available.